# How to install SqlPlus?

Tags: installation

I tried installing sqlplus by following the instruction from [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Oracle%20Instant%20Client). I'm still getting :

```
sqlplus: command not found
```

when I do `sqlplus` from my terminal.

I'm an novice in Ubuntu and I use Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: I think you need to run the alien -i commands with sudo: `sudo alien -i `

Answer (score 42):

First of all you need to download  [Instant Client Downloads](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/instant-client/downloads/index.html). Install alien package so you can install rpm packages by typing following command in terminal.

```
sudo apt-get install alien
```

Once that is done, go to the folder where the rpm files are located and execute the following:

```
sudo alien -i oracle-instantclient*-basic*.rpm
sudo alien -i oracle-instantclient*-sqlplus*.rpm
sudo alien -i oracle-instantclient*-devel*.rpm
```

You need to install `libaio.so`. Type following command to do it:

```
sudo apt-get install libaio1
```

Create Oracle configuration file:

```
sudo sensible-editor /etc/ld.so.conf.d/oracle.conf
```

Put this line in that file:

```
/usr/lib/oracle/<your version>/client/lib/
```

Note - for 64-bit installations, the path will be:

```
/usr/lib/oracle/<your version>/client64/lib/
```

Update the configuration by running following command:

```
sudo ldconfig
```

Try to connect using:

```
sqlplus username/password@//dbhost:1521/SID
```

or:

```
sqlplus testuser/password
```

Note that if you installed the 64-bit version, the client is called `sqlplus64`.

Comment: Thanks for the details. It helped me get the installation completed, especially the part about installing the lib.

Comment: ...until I tried to run sqlplus testuser/password and got "sqlplus: error while loading shared libraries: libsqlplus.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"

Comment: ...and it was because I just touched the oracle.conf file and it turns out you need to add this to it:  

/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client/lib/

(make sure to check that you actually have that path, and thanks to http://marcelozambranav.blogspot.com/2012/08/how-to-install-oracle-sql-plus-on.html). Once I did that, all was well.

Comment: @K .K Patel I followed your instructions but after typing sqlplus in command line,
it prompts to enter a username and password. And i do not know the username and password.
What should i do?

Comment: They have oracle-instantclient* basic,devel,jdbc,odbc,sqlplus,tools,basiclite. Can't I just install the sqlplus one and be done with it?

Comment: this still works the same... one of the qualities of oracle.....

Answer (score 11):

The alien thing didn't work because of:

> Error: cannot open Name index using db5 - Permission denied (13)

Fortunately, there is a more native solution:

Download the **zip** files from [Oracle](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/downloads.html), you need

- *Basic Package (ZIP)* (or *Basic Light Package (ZIP)*)
- *SQL*Plus Package (ZIP)*

The archives extract into the same root folder. Put that folder where you put program files (e.g. `/usr/share` or `$HOME/bin`).

Then create a script that runs the executable after setting the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable, so that libraries are found:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
CLIENTDIR=/usr/share/instantclient_12_2 # <------- adjust this to the path you use
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$CLIENTDIR"
"$CLIENTDIR"/sqlplus "$@"
```

Call it `sqlplus`, make it executable (`chmod 755 sqlplus`) and put it into a directory on your `PATH` (e.g. `/usr/bin/`), so that bash finds it.

That's it, now you can run sqlplus like:

```
sqlplus user/password@host:port/service
```

If it gives you:

> error while loading shared libraries: libaio.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

you need to install the missing library with `sudo apt-get install libaio1`

Answer (score 1):

I think this [link](http://gm.matias.ph/internet-technology/linux-unix/running-oracles-sql-plus-in-linux-ubuntu/) would help. It is pretty descriptive. Make sure you follow all the steps. Still if you have any problems, don't hesitate to comment.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: That what even I have done.. But it doesn't seem to be working.!

Comment: I found this thread http://www.unix.com/ubuntu/157848-sqlplus-command-not-found.html.Try if this would help you any better. I don't have the net speed to download it, else i would have tried it myself and give a better solution.

Comment: @Ant's "it's not working" does not provide us with clues. Show us the output of each command. Then we'll have a general picture of what's going on and where the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

Just as an addendum to @Ketan Patel's great answer:

This simple script, kept together with downloaded rpm files, autpmates the process for futher installs:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
# https://askubuntu.com/a/207145/585248

CURRDIR="$(pwd)";
cd $(dirname "${0}");

# Tools and dependencies:
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install alien libaio1

# Oracle Packages:
echo "Installing instantclient-basic..."
sudo alien -i oracle-instantclient*-basic*.rpm
echo "Installing instantclient-sqlplus..."
sudo alien -i oracle-instantclient*-sqlplus*.rpm
echo "Installing instantclient-devel..."
sudo alien -i oracle-instantclient*-devel*.rpm

echo "Configuring LD path..."
# LD config:
echo /usr/lib/oracle/*/client64/lib \
    | sort -V \
    | tail -n 1 \
    | sudo tee /etc/ld.so.conf.d/oracle.conf \
;
sudo ldconfig

cd "${CURRDIR}"
echo "DONE!!";
```

> **NOTE:** It installs `libaio1` which is the *libaio*'s name at least in Ubuntu (and I think in Debian too). Other distributions may need to adjust this package name to "libaio" or whatever the corresponding package name would be.

**Edit:** Here it is an ehanced version with readline wrapping (credists for [this post](http://blog.cachemiss.com/articles/Using%20readline%20with%20Oracle%20SQL%2APlus.pod)):

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
# https://askubuntu.com/a/207145/585248

CURRDIR="$(pwd)";
cd $(dirname "${0}");

# Tools and dependencies:
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install alien libaio1 rlwrap

# Oracle Packages:
echo "Installing instantclient-basic..."
sudo alien -i oracle-instantclient*-basic*.rpm
echo "Installing instantclient-sqlplus..."
sudo alien -i oracle-instantclient*-sqlplus*.rpm
echo "Installing instantclient-devel..."
sudo alien -i oracle-instantclient*-devel*.rpm

# LD config:
echo "Configuring LD path..."
echo /usr/lib/oracle/*/client64/lib \
    | sort -V \
    | tail -n 1 \
    | sudo tee /etc/ld.so.conf.d/oracle.conf \
;
sudo ldconfig

# Readline wrapping:
echo "Configuring readline wrapping..."
echo "WARNING: You need to manually execute this command or re-read /etc/profile"
echo "if you want readline wrapped 'sqlplus' alias to work in current session".
(cat | sudo tee /etc/profile.d/sqlplus_rlwrap.sh) <<!EOF
alias sqlplus="rlwrap -i -f ~/.sqlplus_history -H ~/.sqlplus_history -s 30000 sqlplus64"
!EOF
touch ~/.sqlplus_history

cd "${CURRDIR}"
echo "DONE!!";
```

It's still Oracle, but at least it makes the pain a little bit more bearable...

Answer (score 0):

Of course the correct installation is from official packages like above ([download Instant Client Downloads](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/instant-client/index-097480.html)), but you can get a full working sqlplus just by copying these files (you can found it in any computer with oracle client installed), and some msb are optitional:

```
./sqlplus
./sqlplus/mesg
./sqlplus/mesg/sp1zhs.msb
./sqlplus/mesg/sp2zhs.msb
./sqlplus/mesg/sp2ptb.msb
./sqlplus/mesg/sp2us.msb
./sqlplus/mesg/sp1us.msb
./sqlplus/mesg/sp1ptb.msb
./sqlplus/mesg/cpyja.msb
./sqlplus/mesg/sp1ja.msb
./sqlplus/mesg/cpyus.msb
./sqlplus/mesg/cpyzhs.msb
./sqlplus/mesg/cpyptb.msb
./sqlplus/mesg/sp2ja.msb
./sqlplus/sqlplus
./README
./lib
./lib/libaio.so.1
./lib/libclntsh.so.11.1
./lib/libsqlplus.so
./lib/libnnz11.so
./lib/libociei.so
```

As aditional dependency, I did include `libaio.so` - it can be installed with `sudo apt-get install libaio1`

So, a sample use can be:

```
cd <PATH_OF_FILES>
ORACLE_HOME=$PWD LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$PWD/lib ./sqlplus/sqlplus user/pw@server:PORT/
```