# SQLPLUS on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: installation, oracle, sql

I'm tryin to install sqplplus on my ubuntu machine, but it didn't really work well till now.. I've did everything in this [article](http://marcelozambranav.blogspot.com/2012/08/how-to-install-oracle-sql-plus-on.html).. and tried "sqlplus" and gave me this error..

```
sqlplus: error while loading shared libraries: libsqlplus.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I've read that that the ORACLE_HOME variable could make this error

so by

```
env | grep ORAC
```

But its not set .. Tried to set it but I needed the ORACLE_BASE var but its also not set..

this [link](http://sabdarsyed.blogspot.com/2008/09/setting-oracle-environment-variable.html) says that the oracle_base should have the value of /oracle/app, but I can't find a diectory called /oracle in my root folder..

Trying

```
$ whereis sqlplus
sqlplus: /usr/bin/sqlplus /usr/bin/X11/sqlplus
$ which sqlplus
/usr/bin/sqlplus
```

btw I visited this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/159939/how-to-install-sqlplus) but it still not working..

What should I do now ?

Comment: I Saw that before .. not working though :)

Comment: Could you specify where it fails?