# No such file or directory when running sqlplus command

Tags: oracle, paths

> root@instance-20220315-0833:/usr/lib/oracle/19.10/client64/bin# ls
>
> *adrci  genezi  sqlplus*
>
> root@instance-20220315-0833:/usr/lib/oracle/19.10/client64/bin# ls -al
> sqlplus
>
> *-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 72384 Apr 16  2021 sqlplus*
>
> root@instance-20220315-0833:/usr/lib/oracle/19.10/client64/bin#
> sqlplus
>
> *-bash: /usr/lib/oracle/19.10/client64/bin/sqlplus: No such file or directory*

The sqlplus file is there, but Ubuntu is not finding it. I have installed all the oracle (rem) packages using alien (going to .tgz first as directly to deb wouldn't work), the libaio1 package and set LD_LIBRARY_PATH and PATH to include the client folder. What am I missing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install SqlPlus?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/159939/how-to-install-sqlplus)

Comment: I'm getting the very same using an Oracle OCI  VM on aarch64, did you ever resolve it?

Comment: @EraserheadIRL Sadly not, I ended up just using a postgresql database on the machine

Answer (score 3):

You need to change the interpreter:

```
mkdir -p /opt/oracle
cd /opt/oracle
curl -LJO https://download.oracle.com/otn_software/linux/instantclient/instantclient-basic-linux-arm64.zip
curl -LJO https://download.oracle.com/otn_software/linux/instantclient/instantclient-sqlplus-linux-arm64.zip
curl -LJO https://download.oracle.com/otn_software/linux/instantclient/instantclient-tools-linux-arm64.zip
curl -LJO https://download.oracle.com/otn_software/linux/instantclient/instantclient-sdk-linux-arm64.zip
curl -LJO https://download.oracle.com/otn_software/linux/instantclient/instantclient-jdbc-linux-arm64.zip
curl -LJO https://download.oracle.com/otn_software/linux/instantclient/instantclient-odbc-linux-arm64.zip

unzip instantclient-basic-linux-arm64.zip
unzip instantclient-sqlplus-linux-arm64.zip
unzip instantclient-tools-linux-arm64.zip
unzip instantclient-sdk-linux-arm64.zip
unzip instantclient-jdbc-linux-arm64.zip
unzip instantclient-odbc-linux-arm64.zip
rm *.zip

sh -c "echo /opt/oracle/instantclient_19_10 > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/oracle-instantclient.conf"
ldconfig

apt -y install patchelf
patchelf --set-interpreter /lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1 instantclient_19_10/sqlplus
patchelf --set-interpreter /lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1 instantclient_19_10/adrci
patchelf --set-interpreter /lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1 instantclient_19_10/exp
patchelf --set-interpreter /lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1 instantclient_19_10/expdp
patchelf --set-interpreter /lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1 instantclient_19_10/genezi
patchelf --set-interpreter /lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1 instantclient_19_10/imp
patchelf --set-interpreter /lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1 instantclient_19_10/impdp
patchelf --set-interpreter /lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1 instantclient_19_10/sqlldr
patchelf --set-interpreter /lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1 instantclient_19_10/sqlplus
patchelf --set-interpreter /lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1 instantclient_19_10/uidrvci
patchelf --set-interpreter /lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1 instantclient_19_10/wrc
```

Comment: Fantastic answer, can conform it worked for me on ubuntu oci instance. Would you mind explaining why this is necessary and what it does?

Comment: I can confirm this also appears to work for Debian 11 running in a Docker container (ddev) on Apple M1 chip. I too would like to know why this is necessary and why Oracle doesn't seem to know about it.